# Get html content of a cell having a checbox with value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the table row

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='post[]' value="1"></td>
    <td>08-Apr-2014</td>
    <td>injj team</td>
    <td>merchant.testyy.com</td>
    <td id="key">a7BuzsEhfcAzkOUT</td>
    <td>ww.test.com/resp233</td>
    <td><a name="deleteButton" href=""><i class="icon-remove text-danger"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

There will be many rows like this.In that I need to get the once in which the checkbox is cehcked

I am able to get checked checkbox's Value when the button with name="deleteButton" is clicked.Now i also need to retrieve the html content of the td with id="key" of the checked checkbox.Is this possible.please help with some logics

I want to get the html content (here its a7BuzsEhfcAzkOUT) of the row having checked checkbox

Comment: I want to get the html content (here its a7BuzsEhfcAzkOUT) of the row having checked checkbox

Comment: then you shouldn't use the attribute `id='key'`, the `id` must be unique in the document

Comment: @Totò There will be many rows like this.In that I need to get the once in which the checkbox is cehcked

Comment: @Totò ya ok.i will use class.But still how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a[name="deleteButton"]').click(function(){
var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('#key').html();
});
```

Comment: yeah.Thanks :)..This one worked like charm.I will mark this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var value = $('#key').text();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R5B3p/)

If there will be multiple rows which contains the 'key' then you should use a class i.e.

```
<td class="key">a7BuzsEhfcAzkOUT</td>
```

now you can use

```
var str = $('tr .key').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete rows whose checkboxes are checked use this... a modification to pixeline's solution.

```
$('a[name="deleteButton"]').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).parents('tr').find("td:eq(0)").find("input").checked)
       return;
    var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('#key').html();
});
```